# How to get permission to edit the file apache2.conf? [Ubuntu]

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions, apache2, file-permissions

I'm a beginner Ruby on Rails Programmer and I'm trying to install Apache2 + Passenger(That's for Rails Deployment).. and at the end of the installation process, Passenger gave me a few lines to add to the file apache2.conf at /etc/apache2/ but I can't override this file.. I have no permission =( I've also uploaded an [image](http://twitpic.com/nblgg/full) showing me the error.

P.S => I'm logged into Ubuntu with my username and password.

Please help! and thanks,
Rodrigo.

Comment: If it worked, you should mark his answer as "accepted" by checking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way is to open the file with the `sudoedit` program, as in

```
sudoedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

which will prompt for your password and then open your editor.

Comment: Can edit it but there is no option for save. Only 'Save as'. How to save it?

Answer (score 5):

After the installation has completed, add phpmyadmin to the apache configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the phpmyadmin config to the file. Include

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner in GNU/Linux, I want to notice, for run command with root privileges run it with sudo:

```
sudo <your_command>
```

If you want to get root privileges for current terminal session (no need to type sudo each command) run:

```
sudo -i
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone considering the number of years since the last post. I tried this, and it worked for me.

```
sudo bash
```

Then the command to edit. Then save the file. Below is the site I got the procedure from.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1845306

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command:

sudo nano /etc/apache2.conf

Comment: That just creates a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the following `chmod 777 usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`
this will enable you to read/write the config file but be warned if you are planning on putting apache2 online you must revert it back to the old permissions `chmod 640 usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`